# Multiple loading GIFs and load multiple PHP pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This works on showing a **single loading GIF** while the php page pulls data from a mySQL database. How do I load more pages and have separate Loading GIFs assigned?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                $("#wait").css("display", "block");
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
            });
            $("#Content").load("sent.php"); //How do I load multiple pages like these and have dedicated 'Loading GIFs'?
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple divs in Content and load php pages in those divs.

Comment: Like having `$("#Content2").load("something.php");` below `$("#Content").load("sent.php");` ??

Comment: Yes you can do this like that